# Can we have more than one colored "Quote Block"?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, design, markdown

This Question is migrate/modified from here: [Can we add a different colored "Quote" box?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3743/can-we-add-a-different-colored-quote-box)

Sometimes answers get long and complicated. Those answers will often have blocks of text that are quotes, and blocks of texts that the main answer, and other blocks of texts that are side notes or interesting tidbits which the writer wishes to draw attention to.

It's common practice these days in tutorials, and other learning material to put different types of information in different colored blocks. Blue for information, red for warnings or gotchas, green for best practices etc.

I would like to propose that ~ or | (or anything else that makes more sense) be used at the beginning of a line to give an alternate color the the quote block which is set by > .  This way different content can be emphasized in different contexts in the most easily comprehended formating.  Though we have all made due with bold and italics and quote blocks for quite some time, I think all our sites, both questions and answers will be improved by an additional color format of the quote block.

An example of how it make text stand out as a different context.
[image: colored boxes]

Comment: I often find myself wanting to differentiate between a quote from the question and a quote from source material I'm referencing in the answer.

Comment: I would instead propose `<!-- quote: green -->` and `<!-- quote-all: red-->`.

Answer (score 2):

This would require custom changes to markdown, which would not be compatible with the specification.

There are other way of distinguishing blocks of text (from using `>` to using code blocks and `<pre>`).

You can also use horizontal rules - `---` on a line by itself to break the post into sections.

Comment: Is there a way to do this (not using ~) that would make such a thing possible? Pre and code blocks aren't an option because many SE sites only allow code to be used in those tags.

Comment: Prettify manages to colorize code without interfering with markdown.  A touch of javascript and some notion of <!-- quote:red --> syntax for markup would work.  Usage would probably be low without an automated process for adding color, of course...

Comment: @Won't I wouldn't want there to be more than 1 or 2 color options. It should be defined by the CSS of the site.

Answer (score 0):

**Can we have more than one colored “Quote Block”?**

No.

---

**It's common practice these days...**

Too bad!

(As well as from being [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) it's a bit non-standard, and unintuitive to read).

---

**I often find myself wanting to differentiate between a quote from the question and a quote from source material I'm referencing in the answer.**

Exactly!

I use bold text to quote the OP (sometimes with a horizontal rule as well, to break the answer into subsections).

I usually avoid bold text for any other purpose (IMO it makes text *less* readable to emphasise words within a paragraph).

The bold text (quoting the OP) thus acts as a section title for the text that follows (answers) it. I could (perhaps should) use `##` instead but I find that looks too big and trashy.

Having done this I can use (reserve) `>` for its intended purpose, i.e. for quoting references in the answer rather than for quoting the OP.